# Can we use pthread instead of NSThread in iPhone apps

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, app-store

Well I have an application that uses both Objective C & c++ but for portability reasons I have tried to use c++ as much as possible.... Now I am confronted with some problem that requires threads I was thinking of using `pthread` instead of `NSThread`... is it Okay to use `pthread`? Will Apple punish me for using it by rejecting my app on the appstore...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSThread` is built around `pthread` anyway

I can't see any reason why using `pthread` would lead to rejection from Apple's part

Comment: Yes. In fact, there's no problem creating a thread using pthreads and invoking [NSThead currentThread] from that thread to get the NSThread version of the pthread or similarly, calling pthread_self from any NSThread created thread.

Comment: @ Does Apple know which technology we use ? In this case is pthread or NSThread. And if yes, any technologies that apple forces developers to use ? Thanks :)

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html - Apple says "Although the NSThread class is the main interface for creating threads in Cocoa applications, you are free to use POSIX threads instead if doing so is more convenient for you." So, there should be no problems, if doing it right.

Answer (score 3):

NSThread is mostly a wrapper around pthread semantics.

Advantages:
- NSThreadWillExitNotification notification when NSThread exits
- A NSMutableDictionary thread-local storage

Limitations:
- you can only create detached NSThread

Be aware that Cocoa needs to know that you want to do multi-threading. It is important to first detach a dummy NSThread so the application can be [considered multi-threaded](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-125024-BAJGFJED).

Answer (score 1):

My app uses pthread API, changes the scheduling policy from SCHED_OTHER to SCHED_FIFO, and changes thread's priority.
It works well.

However, I avoid using Cocoa touch framework APIs in the thread because I don't know the side effect of pthread instead of NSThread.